# whats the meaning of this condition if (buffer[0] & 0x80)

Tags: javascript, cryptography

I came across this code below , trying to understand what the meaning of this condition
    **if (buffer[0] & 0x80)**

```
BigInteger.fromBuffer = function (buffer) {

    if (buffer[0] & 0x80) {
        var byteArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(buffer)

        return new BigInteger([0].concat(byteArray))
    }

    return new BigInteger(buffer)
}
```

Comment: Time to study the documentation for the language you are using.

Comment: What the answers below (so far) don't seem to explain, is *why* this is being done, which may be useful to you. The `buffer[0] & 0x80` will return non-zero if the high-order bit is set. If so the code adds an extra zero byte at the beginning before converting the buffer to a BigInteger. The reason for this is that a buffer with the high-order bit set will result in a negative BigInteger value if converted directly, so this ensures an unsigned (always positive) interpretation of the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the bitwise and-operator. It does an and-operation on each bit position of these two integers and returns a new integer.

As an example:

```
10010001
10000000
```

That would be:

```
10000000
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND

Answer (score 0):

x means 0 or 1.

```
 x    x    x    x      x    x    x    x  
bit7 bit6 bit5 bit4   bit3 bit2 bit1 bit0

buffer[0] = xxxx xxxx; 
0x80      = 1000 0000; 
---------------------  &
buffer[0] = 1xxx xxxx
```

Its means **slice** will be execute when buffer[0] = **1**xxx xxxx;  (**bit 7 of buffer[0] must be 1**, others bits (bit 0-6) can be 0 or 1).